# SharedPreferences Backup Tool for Android

Tags: android, backup

Can anyone recommend a [**SharedPreferences**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) backup tool for Android?

I would like to select individual apps, and backup their SharedPreferences.  I would prefer the backup to be in human readable format.

As a bonus, a *restore* feature would be useful, but is not required.

Requiring root privileges is fine.

Must work on KitKat.

Gratis (free of cost) is preferred, but not required.

Comment: I don't know of an app that does particularly that, but e.g. an ADB Backup contains those files. You could convert the backup file to a tar archive (provided it was not password-protected) and extract the shared prefs. Same applies to backups created using *Titanium Backup*, which directly results in tar files. The former is free of cost, the latter has a free and a paid version.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  How do you use ADB to backup **SharedPreferences** of a single app?  Any way to restore that backup?

Comment: `adb backup -f appname.ab -noapk com.foobar.app` – but that's the entire "data" of the specified app. Also note that if the resulting file is 41 byte or less, the dev decided to block those backups (root needed to work around, plus Xposed and a certain module). Restore is an all-or-nothing: `adb restore appname.adb`. Or picking the shared prefs out of the backup with `ab2tar`, and using root powers to put them back in place :)

Comment: @Izzy!  Thanks Izzy!!!  Which Xposed module?  Is there a link that describes the workaround?

Comment: BackupAllApps is the module. Just install and enable. No further description required :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  I'll take a look.  I'm still looking for something that meets the requirements above, but in the meantime, your suggestions are extremely helpful.  Thank you!